# HTML button style

Tags: html, button, styles

I am making some web-site and need to use this kind of buttons. Have you all seen this kind of button?

Thank you for reading it.

[image]

Comment: Those are not any special buttons. They are normal HTML buttons, with different color code and labels. What matters is the functionality that binds them.

Comment: That's really easy to build. If you don't know how to create that input, you need to use span or div before, and then use input. Then you need to use Javascript or jQuery to make a function when you press on certain buttons to add value. Otherwise, you can check codepen.io or other similar websites.

Comment: Thank you guys. I just thought it is a special button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than writing one from scratch, you can try out buttons available at 
   (getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons)   -or-
you can visit (materializecss.com/buttons.html) -> I think, this has got what you are looking for

Then you have sites to generate buttons for you online, from http://livetools.uiparade.com/button-builder.html and http://www.bestcssbuttongenerator.com/